# Cannot find class in classpath: when running pom.xml within Eclipse + TestNg

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-2, testng

I am getting the following error when try to run pom.xml as Maven Build (m2 Added the apache-maven-3.2.1-bin lib).I am using Eclipse Kepler IDE.
    If I run MytestXml file manually as TestNg then it works fine.The below error is only when I try to run the pom.xml file

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project seleniumtests: Execution default-test of goal     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the 
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.proj.website.test.MyProjectXML


POM.xml :-
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cap</groupId>
    <artifactId>seleniumtests</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>

                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>MyTest.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

MyTest.xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="logon Verfication" verbose="3" parallel="tests">
    <parameter name="appURL" value="http://www.dummysite.com" ></parameter> 

    <test name="Test for Demo And Security">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"></parameter>

        <classes>
               <class name="com.proj.website.test.MyProjectXML" />
        </classes>

    </test>
```

Comment: its not able to find MyProjectXML. can you provide the full path to the xml and check if it works.

Comment: Where is your MyProjectXML.java file located? It has to go under src/test/java

Comment: Hi all the test java files are under \src\com\mycap\website\test and this is the error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project seleniumtests: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.mycap.website.test.MyProjectXML

Comment: how to change this default  path to point to \src\com\mycap\website\test to pick up the test files ?I tried below and it still gives the same error  <build>
      <testSourceDirectory>src/com/mycap/website/test/</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>

Comment: `<testSourceDirectory>src/</testSourceDirectory>` might work, but this might get you into trouble with other maven plugins because now both source directories point to the same actual directory. So this is a really bad practice. Also note that you may ship test classes with your package then.

Comment: Hi SpaceTrucker then what would be the correct way to call the test class which do not lie under src/test/java.I have seen that most of the  structure of the code would be customised like com.xyz.abc.testfiles.Is  it problem with surefire ? or is it just that its compulsory to have everything under src/test/java – for Maven to pickup the test files ?

Comment: can u paste "MyTest.xml" in the same folder as testng.xml and try to run it via terminal/cmd... using this steps... 1.Navigate to project folder (Level above src folder..not in src) 2. run command "mvn test"